# how to get the count of columns with same value for each row in sql

Tags: sql, select

eg: table

```
id a  b  c  d 
1  Y  Y  Y  N
2  N  Y  Y  N
```

what I need is

```
id a  b  c  d  e
1  Y  Y  Y  N  3
2  N  Y  Y  N  2
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL functions generally aggregate data across rows, not columns, so I don't think there's a generic way of doing this. You could, however, for this usecase, use a series of `case` expressions:

```sql
SELECT id, a, b, c, d,
       CASE a WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE b WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE c WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE d WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS e
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: if you value is only Y it is correct but if count N and Y this is not correct answer

Comment: @MBadrian According to the OP'd sample data, only Ys should be counted

Comment: hi Mureinik, thank you I got it but  I want to insert the e column to existing table please help

Comment: Yes but i think about general solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  mytable SET e=
       CASE a WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE b WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE c WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE d WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM
```

Comment: It may be a great answer, but without an explanation or where the error was, it would be hard for anyone to find it useful.